# generic rule for parsing custom group of strings using boost::spirit::x3

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I am trying make a generic rule for my use case with using boost::spirit::x3.

use cases are

1. input "string,string" output [string, string]
2. input "string.string,string" output [string.string, string]
3. input "string.0.string.1.string,string" output [string.0.string.1.string, string]

[**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85192ff6c3a7b42f)

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
//#define DEBUG_SYMBOLS
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit;

auto myRule = +x3::lexeme[ +x3::alnum >> -x3::char_('.')] % +x3::char_(',');

void print(std::string test, std::vector<std::string>& allHeroes)
{
    std::cout << "----" << test << std::endl;
    for (auto& hero: allHeroes)
    {
        std::cout << hero << std::endl;    
    }
    std::cout << "-----------------------------" << std::endl;
}

void test_1()
{
    std::string heroSelections = "mirana,slark";
    std::vector<std::string> allHeroes;
    boost::spirit::x3::parse(heroSelections.begin(), heroSelections.end(), myRule, allHeroes);
    print("test_1", allHeroes);
    if (allHeroes.size() == 2)
    {
        assert(allHeroes[0] == "mirana");
        assert(allHeroes[1] == "slark"); 
        std::cout << "PASS" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "FAIL" << std::endl;
    }
}

void test_2()
{
    std::string heroSelections = "hero.0.range.1.mirana,slark";
    std::vector<std::string> allHeroes;
    boost::spirit::x3::parse(heroSelections.begin(), heroSelections.end(), myRule, allHeroes);
    print("test_2", allHeroes);
    if (allHeroes.size() == 2)
    {
        assert(allHeroes[0] == "hero.0.range.1.mirana");
        assert(allHeroes[1] == "slark");  
        std::cout << "PASS" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "FAIL" << std::endl;
    }
}

void test_3()
{
    std::string heroSelections = "hero.0.mirana,slark";
    std::vector<std::string> allHeroes;
    boost::spirit::x3::parse(heroSelections.begin(), heroSelections.end(), myRule, allHeroes);
    print("test_3", allHeroes);
    if (allHeroes.size() == 2)
    {
        assert(allHeroes[0] == "hero.0.mirana");
        assert(allHeroes[1] == "slark");   
        std::cout << "PASS" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "FAIL" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    test_1();
    test_2();
    test_3();
    return 0;
}
```

i have tried rules

1. `auto myRule = +x3::lexeme[ +x3::alnum >> -x3::char_('.')] % +x3::char_(',');`

   my understanding:

   `+x3::alnum >> -x3::char_('.')` allows format string and string.string and string.string.string until  `% +x3::char_(',')` is met
2. `auto myRule = +x3::alnum >> +x3::lexeme[ +x3::alnum >> -x3::char_('.')] % +x3::char_(',');`

`+x3::alnum` allows format string and then `+x3::lexeme[ +x3::alnum >> -x3::char_('.')]` allows all string.string until `% +x3::char_(',')`.

But clearly my understanding is incorrect here.

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [documented](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator.html), just *check* your understanding:

> The list operator, `a % b`, is a binary operator that matches a list of one or more repetitions of `a` separated by occurrences of `b`. This is equivalent to `a >> *(b >> a)`.

Simplifying the test program making it readable (without all the repetition):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/779268f5d0211436)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

using Heroes = std::vector<std::string>;
struct {
    std::string txt;
    Heroes      expected;
} testcases[]{
    {
        "mirana,slark",
        {"mirana", "slark"},
    },
    {
        "hero.0.range.1.mirana,slark",
        {"hero.0.range.1.mirana", "slark"},
    },
    {
        "hero.0.mirana,slark",
        {"hero.0.mirana", "slark"},
    },
};

int main() {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    auto const myRule = +x3::lexeme[+x3::alnum >> -x3::char_('.')] % +x3::lit(',');

    for (auto [test, expected] : testcases) {
        Heroes actual;
        parse(test.begin(), test.end(), myRule, actual);

        fmt::print("{}\t'{}' -> {}\n", (actual == expected ? "PASS" : "FAIL"), test, actual);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
PASS    'mirana,slark' -> ["mirana", "slark"]
FAIL    'hero.0.range.1.mirana,slark' -> ["hero.", "0.", "range.", "1.", "mirana", "slark"]
FAIL    'hero.0.mirana,slark' -> ["hero.", "0.", "mirana", "slark"]
```

I'd suggest simplification like

```
auto const hero   = +x3::char_("a-zA-Z0-9.");
auto const myRule = hero % ',';
```

[Printing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be68c11d7b738f3a):

```
PASS    'mirana,slark' -> ["mirana", "slark"]
PASS    'hero.0.range.1.mirana,slark' -> ["hero.0.range.1.mirana", "slark"]
PASS    'hero.0.mirana,slark' -> ["hero.0.mirana", "slark"]
```

However, if you actually want to be stricter than the tests suggest, consider:

```
auto const hero   = x3::raw[ +x3::alnum % '.' ];
auto const myRule = hero % ','; // or % +x3::lit(',');
```

Also [printing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8296c7219d460a0a) the same

```
PASS    'mirana,slark' -> ["mirana", "slark"]
PASS    'hero.0.range.1.mirana,slark' -> ["hero.0.range.1.mirana", "slark"]
PASS    'hero.0.mirana,slark' -> ["hero.0.mirana", "slark"]
```